# Fade CSS (not transition)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-transitions

Is there any way to recreate the fade effect in  [this](https://stripe.com/gb/about) site. I tried searching but i only got fad animations only.

[image: blocks]

I only want the fade property css.

TIA

Comment: please clearify your que .

Comment: Use the browser's inspect tool and examine their code to see how they did it. Hint: it's a linear gradient from transparent to white on the `.diagram-infra:after` element.

Comment: @DrewReese ThankYou. I missed that part. I thought it was something to do with transitions and all. Thanks fot the help.

Answer (score 1):

The site you linked set a gradient that fades to white (`#fff`) using the `background` property in that element's CSS:

```
background: linear-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), #fff 50%);
```

You don't have to do it this way, though. For example, you could try something like this:

```html
<div class="fader">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" style=" -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 0%, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))">
</div>
```